# Posting nested models in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having an issue posting nested models in my Express/Mongoose/Mongo application. When I try to have both the single container model and the multiple inner models post only the outer model (Orders) shows up in the database.

Schemas:

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    order: ObjectId,
    type: String // ex: Sandwich
});
var orderSchema = new Schema({
    name:  String,
    items: [Item.itemSchema]
});
```

API:

```
var Order = require('../models/order.js');
var Item = require('../models/item.js');

exports.createOrder = function(req, res) {
  new Order({name: req.body.name}, function(err, order){
    order.items.forEach(function (err, item){
      new Item({order: order._id, type: item.type}).save;
    });
  }).save();
};
```

Curl Post:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "John Smith","items": [{"type": "sandwich"},{"type": "sub"}]}' http://localhost:3000/order
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Order()` doesn't take a callback.

a) Do you intend to save the "items" embedded with the Order or

b) Do you intend to save the items in a separate collection or

c) both?